# How to implement simultaneous git push to the same repo?

Tags: git, github-actions, workflow

I wrote a Github Actions workflow that scales down ecs services and autoscaling groups of our 16 QA environments for the night.
Changes are done using Terragrunt.

The process identifies the environments that should go down and creates a matrix based on the environment_name.
And then another job in the workflow edits the relevant terragrunt.hcl files per element in the matrix (each element is an environment) and commits them.

Sometimes there's only one environment that should go down and sometimes more, but since it's a matrix strategy then every element runs through the same steps.

The problem I've bumped into is that when there's more than one environment that should go down, it seems like there's a race of which element of the matrix is the first one to push the changes.
Then, randomly one of the environments finishes the push successfully while all the others fail as they are not aware to the push that happened previously by other elements in the matrix.

So I've implemented a sleep based on a random retry interval so they are no longer pushing at the same time, but I still get this error:

```
[master c938bb8d4] Shutting down for the night environment qa-devops-1
 49 files changed, 52 insertions(+), 52 deletions(-)
To https://github.com/company/terraform-live
 ! [remote rejected]     master -> master (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': is at 18c03cb731109dfd57609b08fa951c27c5d31997 but expected 1d390054db22f56b6e0bb53989f265bbb1728eec)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/company/terraform-live'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This is the relevant step from the workflow:

```
      - name: Adds changes to Git
        id: git-push
        run: |
          set -ex -o pipefail
          git config --global user.name github-actions-workflows
          git config --global user.email devops+github-actions-workflows@company
          env_name=${{ matrix.unprotected_environment }}
          RANDOM=$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19)
          random_wait_interval=$(echo $(( $RANDOM % 15 + 1 )))
          cd ${{ github.workspace }}/${{ env.qa_processing_tg_dir }}/${{ env.qa_envs_region}}/${env_name}
          git status
          git pull
          git add ecs-service
          git add autoscaling/product
          git add ecs-capacity-provider/service
          cd ${{ github.workspace }}/${{ env.qa_commercial_tg_dir }}/${{ env.qa_envs_region}}/${env_name}
          git add ecs-service
          git add ecs-capacity-provider/service
          git commit -m "Shutting down for the night environment ${env_name}"
          echo "Waiting $random_wait_interval seconds to continue..."
          sleep $random_wait_interval
          git push
          export COMMIT_ID=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
          echo "::set-output name=commit_id::${COMMIT_ID}"
          echo "COMMIT_ID: ${COMMIT_ID}"
```

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Did you try fetching and pushing in sequence instead of in parallel to see if this conflicts also occur?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't happen if ran in sequence but then I'm unable to wait for a successful check suite end of each environment separately (using jitterbit/await-check-suites@v1), that's why I've used matrix in the first place, in order to be able to wait for each environment push which triggers another workflow that runs terragrunt - actually making the changes.